# readin html file in python

Tags: html, python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("website.html","r") as file:
    content=file.read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
print(soup.title)7
```

"can some one tell my the problem it does't  read the html file"

I want the answer to read the html file

Comment: is the `7` supposed to be there? else, you can try printing `print(soup.title.text)`.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your question. It's generally recommended to copy-paste the error message below your question -- this would help identify the problem. 
Otherwise, I think the suggestion by @najeem is good.